# I need to find a dictionary key that can appear in multiple different values, and sum data as a result

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following dictionary sample, and ideally what I'd like to do (just once at a certain point) is end up with the groupTotals being the sum of each "time" value where the key (eg 98154646703) appears in multiple "group" values. So, for example:

The first two items below would have a groupTotal of 960 because 98154646703 appears in both the first and second item's "group" value. The next three would have a groupTotal of 82,260 etc.

I can make my way around dictionaries but this is a little too complex for my brain at the moment I'm afraid! Hopefully this all makes sense and there's a way to do it?

```
  {
  "_testList": {
    "98154646703": {
      "time": 180.0,
      "group": "98154646703, 98149569526"
      "groupTotal": 0
    },
    "98149569526": {
      "time": 780.0,
      "group": "98149569526, 98154646703"
      "groupTotal": 0
    },
    "98863457238": {
      "time": 81480.0,
      "group": "98979117899, 97989042539, 98863457238"
      "groupTotal": 0
    },
    "97989042539": {
      "time": 390.0,
      "group": "98979117899, 98863457238, 97989042539"
      "groupTotal": 0
    },
    "98979117899": {
      "time": 390.0,
      "group": "98979117899, 98863457238, 97989042539"
      "groupTotal": 0
   }
```

Comment: You can split the task in two: first design a model of this data as C# class(es) and implement the deserialization from JSON. Then operate on this model (maybe using LINQ SelectMany, GroupBy and Sum) to produce the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly trivial using a dictionary. Something like:

```
var dict = _testList.ToDictionary(i => i.Key, i => i);
foreach(var item in dict.Values){
    var groupTotal = item.Group.Sum(g => dict[g.Key].Time);
    // Use group total in some way
}
```

This of course assumes you have an appropriate c# type and deserialized your json to a list of that type. I.e. Something like

```
public class MyClass{
 public string Key {get;set;}
 public double Time {get;set;}
 public List<string> Group {get;set;}
 public double GroupTotal {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, that gives me an idea for sure, appreciate it :) My only issue is that it's parsing each letter from the group value, rather than each word (or group of numbers I guess), but I'll poke away at it:

`'char' does not contain a definition for 'Key' and no accessible extension method 'Key' accepting a first argument of type 'char' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: @simonk83 As I mentioned, the first step should be to deserialize your list into *.Net objects*. Do not try to work with json data directly.

Comment: Ah sorry, 4 month old baby here so my brain is swiss cheese (I shouldn't be attempting this right now anyway, but it's keeping me sane).

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You need to split groups in an array/list and then treat each of value of this list as a key to _testList.

```
public class Root
{
    public Dictionary<string, Data> _testList { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public double time { get; set; }
    public string group { get; set; }
    public double groupTotal { get; set; }
}


static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{\"_testList\":{\"98154646703\":{\"time\":180.0,\"group\":\"98154646703,98149569526\",\"groupTotal\":0},\"98149569526\":{\"time\":780.0,\"group\":\"98149569526,98154646703\",\"groupTotal\":0},\"98863457238\":{\"time\":81480.0,\"group\":\"98979117899,97989042539,98863457238\",\"groupTotal\":0},\"97989042539\":{\"time\":390.0,\"group\":\"98979117899,98863457238,97989042539\",\"groupTotal\":0},\"98979117899\":{\"time\":390.0,\"group\":\"98979117899,98863457238,97989042539\",\"groupTotal\":0}}}";
    Root obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Root>(json);
    foreach(var item in obj._testList)
    {
        var groups = item.Value.group.Split(',');
        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            item.Value.groupTotal += obj._testList[group].time;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Danial, I'll give this a crack as well!